# Is the Kernel of a homomorphism normal only when the homomorphism is into ? Why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

In the Text Herstein's Algebra :

In the Homomorphism section, he defines Kernel as :

If $\phi$ is a homomorphism of G **into** G, the kernel of $\phi$, $K_\phi$, is
defined by $K_\phi$ = {$x \in G $ | $\phi(x)$ = e, e = identity element of G}.

And then states this particular Lemma :

If $\phi$ is a homomorphism of G **into** $\bar{G}$ with kernel K, then K is a
normal subgroup of G.

Here, why the mapping between G and $\bar{G}$ has to be into ?
Will K be a normal subgroup if mapping is onto ?

Comment: It seems like the word "into" is not referring to a property the homomorphism has, it's just saying what the codomain is. Kernels are always normal.

Comment: Which book does you mean? Abstract Algebra or Topics in Algebra?

Comment: When he talks about inverse images of $\bar{g}$ other than $\bar{e}$, then he defines $\phi$ as a homomorphism of G onto $\bar{G}$. 
Why this difference in defining Kernel (i.e. all inverse of $\bar{g}$ equal to $\bar{e}$) and when defining all inverse for $\bar{g}$ other than $\bar{e}$ ?

Comment: @AlanWang Topics in Algebra, 2nd Edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your confusion arises from the wording "into".

For a function $f:A\rightarrow B$, we normally say that $f$ is a function from $A$ **to** $B$. Although in this book the author sometimes said $f$ is a function (or mapping) from $A$ **into** $B$, they are basically the same thing. They mean that for every $a\in A$, there must be a unique element $b\in B$ such that $f(a)=b$.

Let $G,\bar{G}$ be two groups.
As long as $f:G\rightarrow \bar{G}$ is a homomorphism (that is, $f:G\rightarrow \bar{G}$ is a well-defined function such that $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y\in G$), the kernel of $f$ is always a normal subgroup of $G$.

So if furthermore the function $f$ is onto (or surjective), the kernel of $f$ is still normal in $G$.

Comment: Got it. 
Also while defining isomorphism, Herstein states any homomorphism which is one-to-one is an isomorphism (whether it is onto or into). 
While in other text, it is stated that bijectivity is a must. 
Which of the two definitions should we go with ?

Comment: @latus_rectum Bijectivity is a must. An isomorphism must be surjective (or onto).